# How do I indent an unordered list properly? margin-left won't work!

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Hi I'm creating an email but I'm not sure how to adjust the automated indent on the bullets. I'm sure theres a simple fix. Margin-left doesn't seem to work!

Thanks for your help
Regards
Judi

```
       .bullets{
        width:255px;
        color:white;
        font-size:11px;
        margin-right: 2em;
        list-style: none;
        line-height:15px;
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 1em;
        display:inline;
    }

     <table class="bullets" border="0">
                <tr>
                  <td><ul>
                    <li> Select products 
</li>
                  </ul></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <ul>
                      <li> Incorporate </li>
                  </ul></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><ul>
                    <li> on site</li>
                  </ul></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to apply the `margin-left: 0;` to the `li` itself.

```
.bullets li {
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}
```

You might find you also need to apply it to the `ul` aswell.

```
.bullets ul, .bullets li {
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}
```

Check also that that `table` and `td` do not have any padding or margin applied to them.

```
.bullets, .bullets td, .bullets ul, .bullets li {
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Less is more:

```
<ul>
    <li>Abc</li>
    <li>Def
       <ul>
           <li>Ghi</li>
           <li>Jkl</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Mno</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You would be better to follow this example if you can as it is simpler and easier to manage.

Comment: Ha - this is exactly what I was searching for - I would definitely upvote except this doesn't actually answer the original question!

Comment: Without showing the relevant css code, this html snippet could appear any number of ways. Downvoted because not only does this not answer the question, it is an example of how to answer a question in a vague and useless way. Why anyone upvoted this is beyond me - a question of "can I nest lists instead of using a table" could have gotten a much simpler answer of "yes"

Answer (score 3):

```
  .bullets{
    width:255px;
    color:white;
    font-size:11px;
    margin-right: 2em;
    list-style: none;
    line-height:15px;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 1em;
    display:inline;
}

<table class="bullets" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <ul>
      <li> Select products</li>
      <li> Incorporate </li>
      <li> on site</li>
    </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Bullet indent should be controlled by margin-left.

Comment: Thanks ah I see Margin-left -3em